# acpi_listen returns different result in Ubuntu than Arch Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, keyboard, acpi

Ubuntu is able to detect my Lenovo "Mic Mute" button with `acpi_listen`, but when I try it on Arch Linux, there is no output available.

Model:  `Thinkpad X220 4290LY9`

Tried to add `acpi_osi=Linux` in kernel cmdline, but mic mute still has no output from `acpi_listen`.

After adding `acpi_osi` option, the led of my output mute button, no longer toggles, but it still functions.

Comment: Apart from comparing their `dmesg` output, [adding `acpi_osi="Linux"` to the Kernel command line could help](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Mute_button) (Does it?)

Comment: @sr_ tried , no luck

Comment: See if `xev` can detect it. You can use `amixer` to mute, though that might not be what you want.

Comment: @hesse , no either